# Are there any exceptions in the NETWORKDAYS formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am calculating the difference of hours betweens two days excluding weekends but I am getting 9hr less in my result. In my project they are calculating on severity basis, so I include an IF command in the below formula.

I am using the below formula:

```
=IF(B30<3,E30,((NETWORKDAYS(C30,D30)-1-MOD(C30,1)+MOD(D30,1))*24))
```

I am using the above formula for below example but I am not getting the right answer.

> B30 (Severity = 3)
>
> C30 (Opentime = 4/10/2013 3:04)
>
> D30 (Closed time = 4/14/2013 15:41)
>
> E30 (Total time including weekends = 108.6141)
>
> Correct ans:
>
> 68.96 hrs

Here C30 is start time and D30 is closed time. I am getting 60.61 hrs but the correct answer is 68.96 hrs.

Ticket is opened on 10th April at 3:04am and closed on 14th April at 15:41. Here Business days are 10,11 and 12 April and if we calcluate it manually then its comes as below:

> (As open time is 3:04 AM so we have 20:96 hrs in hand from 24 hrs)

20:96 hrs for 10th Apr + 24 hrs for 11th Apr + 24 hrs for 12th Apr = 68.96 hrs but I am getting only 60.61 hrs by the above formula.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is only guaranteed to work correctly if start and end times are always within working hours - because your end date is a Sunday you get the wrong result, try this formula to cope with **any** start/end dates

`=IF(B30<3,E30,(NETWORKDAYS(C30,D30)-NETWORKDAYS(C30,C30)*MOD(C30,1)+ NETWORKDAYS(D30,D30)*(MOD(D30,1)))*24)`

Note: the correct answer is **68.933** because 56 minutes is 0.933 of an hour (approx).....